# Validation on the hidden fields on knockoutJS

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js, observable

I am trying perform validation on the fields entered on the KnockoutJS, the issue is validation in the hidden fields. The page is like this

[image]

When the Has Customer Account Number? field is selected I want the Billing address is same as Shipping Address  and Billing Address should be invisible. So the Email And First Name need to be required in that scenario. I want to the fields to be required only when then both fields are unchecked, even if one is checked then no validation should be fired on the Billing Address section.

```
        <div class="col-md-6" data-bind="visible: !sameAsShippingAddress() && !hasCustomerAccNum()">
            <h4>Billing Address:</h4>
            <div class="form-group required">
                <label for="EmailCompetitor_Billing" class="control-label">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" maxlength="150" id="EmailCompetitor_Billing" name="EmailCompetitor_Billing" class="form-control" data-bind="value: emailCompetitor_Billing" required />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group required">
                <label for="FirstNameCompetitor_Billing" class="control-label">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" maxlength="150" id="FirstNameCompetitor_Billing" name="FirstNameCompetitor_Billing" class="form-control" data-bind="value: firstNameCompetitor_Billing" required />
            </div>
```

And the JS is like

```
self.emailCompetitor_Billing = ko.observable().extend({ required: { params: true, message: "Required! Please enter a valid email" }, email: { params: true, message: "Required! Please enter a valid email" } });
self.firstNameCompetitor_Billing = ko.observable().extend({ required: { params: true, message: "Required! Please First Name " } });
```

I tried to set the onlyIf like below in the required section atleast hoping it will fire the validation rules only when the Has Customer Account Number is unchecked but no luck

```
 self.firstNameCompetitor_Billing = ko.observable().extend({ required: { params: true, message: "Required! Please First Name ", onlyIf: !self.hasCustomerAccNum } });
```

I am very newto this KnockoutJS world any help is greatly appreciated

Update I tried to make the required

```
  self.sameAsShippingAddress = ko.observable(false);
  self.hasCustomerAccNum = ko.observable(false);
  .......
  self.sameAsShippingAddress = ko.observable().extend({ required: false });
  self.hasCustomerAccNum = ko.observable().extend({ required: false });
  .......
  self.firstNameCompetitor_Billing = ko.observable().extend({ required: { params: true, message: "Required! Please First Name ", onlyIf: !self.hasCustomerAccNum() } });
```

It throws error on page load `knockout.validation.min.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: r.condition is not a function`

Comment: Assuming `self.hasCustomerAccNum` is an observable, try changing the onlyIf attribute to `!self.hasCustomerAccNum()` to make the required extension respond to changes.

Comment: @PhilipBijker I did try to add that I am getting error `knockout.validation.min.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: r.condition is not a function`. I have updated the question

Comment: Where is `r.condition` defined? I don't see it in your above code

Answer (score 0):

you can add data-validation attribute in data-bind like this.
data-bind="attr: { 'data-validation':isVisible?'required':false}"